# Complete missing, non-overlapping date ranges

Tags: r

My question is a variation on [Complete missing dates based on start and end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76015556/complete-missing-dates-based-on-start-and-end). I would like to fill in missing date ranges using a floor date and ceiling date, but the date ranges in my example should be non-overlapping.

```
have <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1),
                 date1 = as.Date(c("2000-01-29", "2000-07-16")),
                 date2 = as.Date(c("2000-07-15", "2001-04-30")))

> have
  ID      date1      date2
1  1 2000-01-29 2000-07-15
2  1 2000-07-16 2001-04-30

want <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1),
                 date1 = as.Date(c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-29", "2000-07-16", "2001-05-01")),
                 date2 = as.Date(c("2000-01-28", "2000-07-15", "2001-04-30", "2001-07-31")))

> want
  ID      date1      date2
1  1 2000-01-01 2000-01-28
2  1 2000-01-29 2000-07-15
3  1 2000-07-16 2001-04-30
4  1 2001-05-01 2001-07-31
```

Using the answer to the previous post nearly works, except that date2 and the following date1 overlap.

```
library(dplyr)
start <- as.Date("2000-01-01"); end <- as.Date("2001-07-31")

ex <- have %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(newdate1 = c(start, date2), newdate2 = c(date1, end)) %>%
  rename(date1 = newdate1, date2 = newdate2) %>%
  filter(date2 > date1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  bind_rows(have) %>%
  arrange(ID, date1)

> ex
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     ID date1      date2     
  <dbl> <date>     <date>    
1     1 2000-01-01 2000-01-29
2     1 2000-01-29 2000-07-15
3     1 2000-07-15 2000-07-16
4     1 2000-07-16 2001-04-30
5     1 2001-04-30 2001-07-31
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be as simple as adding a `+1` and a `-1` in the summarize line?

```
ex <- have %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(newdate1 = c(start, date2+1), newdate2 = c(date1-1, end)) %>%
  rename(date1 = newdate1, date2 = newdate2) %>%
  filter(date2 > date1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  bind_rows(have) %>%
  arrange(ID, date1)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
     ID date1      date2     
  <dbl> <date>     <date>    
1     1 2000-01-01 2000-01-28
2     1 2000-01-29 2000-07-15
3     1 2000-07-16 2001-04-30
4     1 2001-04-30 2001-07-31

identical(want, ex)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Do you have any advice on my variation of the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76427407/complete-missing-non-overlapping-date-ranges-truncated-variable-start-end-dat?