# Complete missing, non-overlapping date ranges, truncated, variable start/end dates, indicator var

Tags: r, dplyr

My question is a variation on [Complete missing dates based on start and end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76015556/complete-missing-dates-based-on-start-and-end) and [Complete missing, non-overlapping date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76393814/complete-missing-non-overlapping-date-ranges). Here is my starting data:

```
have <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1),
                 date1 = as.Date(c("1999-09-01", "2000-01-29")),
                 date2 = as.Date(c("2000-01-15", "2001-04-30")),
                 start = as.Date(c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-01")),
                 end = as.Date(c("2001-07-31", "2001-07-31")),
                 ind = c(1,1))

> have
  ID      date1      date2      start        end ind
1  1 1999-09-01 2000-01-15 2000-01-01 2001-07-31   1
2  1 2000-01-29 2001-04-30 2000-01-01 2001-07-31   1
```

My desired output looks like this:

```
want <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
                 date1 = as.Date(c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-16", "2000-01-29", "2001-05-01")),
                 date2 = as.Date(c("2000-01-15", "2000-01-28", "2001-04-30", "2001-07-31")),
                 ind = c(1,0,1,0))

> want
  ID      date1      date2 ind
1  1 2000-01-01 2000-01-15 1
2  1 2000-01-16 2000-01-28 0
3  1 2000-01-29 2001-04-30 1
4  1 2001-05-01 2001-07-31 0
```

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Add lines with the missing date intervals between a floor and ceiling date (my previous post)
2. Use date floor and ceiling which vary by group ID
3. Exclude date ranges before the given floor date
4. Create an indicator variable `ind` keeping track of date ranges present in the starting data (time when feature is observed = 1) or not (time when feature is not observed = 0)

So far I have this code from the linked posts but the output is not quite what I'm going for:

```
library(dplyr)
ex <- have %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(newdate1 = c(start, date2+1), newdate2 = c(date1-1, end)) %>%
  rename(date1 = newdate1, date2 = newdate2) %>%
  filter(date2 > date1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  bind_rows(have) %>%
  arrange(ID, date1)

> ex
# A tibble: 5 × 6
     ID date1      date2      start      end          ind
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1     1 1999-09-01 2000-01-15 2000-01-01 2001-07-31     1
2     1 2000-01-01 2000-01-28 NA         NA            NA
3     1 2000-01-16 2001-07-31 NA         NA            NA
4     1 2000-01-29 2001-04-30 2000-01-01 2001-07-31     1
5     1 2001-05-01 2001-07-31 NA         NA            NA
```

Thank you.

**Update:**
Recoding the intervals so they fall within the floor and ceiling dates is simple enough:

```
have2 <- have %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(date1new = ifelse(date1<start & date2>start,start,date1),
         date2new = ifelse(date2>end & date1<end, end, date2),
         date1new = as.Date(date1new, origin = "1970-01-01"),
         date2new = as.Date(date2new, origin = "1970-01-01")) %>%
  select(ID, (start:date2new)) %>%
  rename(date1 = date1new, date2 = date2new) %>%
ungroup()

> have2
# A tibble: 2 × 6
     ID start      end          ind date1      date2     
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <dbl> <date>     <date>    
1     1 2000-01-01 2001-07-31     1 2000-01-01 2000-01-15
2     1 2000-01-01 2001-07-31     1 2000-01-29 2001-04-30
```

I still can't get my desired output using the example script.

```
ex2 <- have2 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(newdate1 = c(start, date2+1), newdate2 = c(date1-1, end)) %>%
  rename(date1 = newdate1, date2 = newdate2) %>%
  filter(date2 > date1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  bind_rows(have2) %>%
  arrange(ID, date1)

> ex2
# A tibble: 5 × 6
     ID date1      date2      start      end          ind
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1     1 2000-01-01 2000-01-28 NA         NA            NA
2     1 2000-01-01 2000-01-15 2000-01-01 2001-07-31     1
3     1 2000-01-16 2001-07-31 NA         NA            NA
4     1 2000-01-29 2001-04-30 2000-01-01 2001-07-31     1
5     1 2001-05-01 2001-07-31 NA         NA            NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it. The main mistake was passing the `start` and `end` values as a column, not as a value, in

```
newdate1 = c(start, date2+1), newdate2 = c(date1-1, end)
```

This way, it's adding the whole `start` column at the beginning, not just one value. That's why your output had extra rows. You wanted to do something like `start[1]`.

Besides that, we can do some minor improvements.

1. Create an `id = 0` column in the `summarize`;
2. Make your `mutate` more compact;
3. Entirely remove rows where both dates fall before the `start` of after the `end` with a filter;
4. Deselect `start` and `end` columns before the `bind_rows()`.

```
have2 <- have %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(! (date1 < start & date2 < start) | (date1 > end & date2 > end)) %>% # Item 3
  mutate(date1 = ifelse(date1<start,start,date1) %>% as.Date(origin = "1970-01-01"),
         date2 = ifelse(date2>end, end, date2)  %>% as.Date(origin = "1970-01-01")) # Item 2
# You don't necessarily need to ungroup, as we want grouped data for the summarize

have2 %>%
  summarize(newdate1 = c(start[1], date2+1),
            newdate2 = c(date1-1, end[1]),
            ind = 0) %>% # Item 1
  rename(date1 = newdate1, date2 = newdate2) %>%
  filter(date2 > date1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  bind_rows(select(have2, -c(start, end))) %>% # Item 4
  arrange(ID, date1)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
     ID date1      date2        ind
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1     1 2000-01-01 2000-01-15     1
2     1 2000-01-16 2000-01-28     0
3     1 2000-01-29 2001-04-30     1
4     1 2001-05-01 2001-07-31     0
```

**Alternative `mutate`:**

If you know that your data is always in increasing dates, you can just change the first value of date1, and the last of date2:

```
mutate(date1 = c(if(date1[1] < start[1]) start[1] else date1[1], date1[-1]),
       date2 = c(date2[-n()], if(date2[n()] > end[1]) end[1] else date2[n()]))
```

This way you avoid unnecessary checks and don't lose the date formatting.

Comment: Thank you. In the first filter() call, don't we need to wrap the whole line in !() as in:`filter(!((date1 < start & date2 < start) | (date1 > end & date2 > end))) # Item 3`